# C++ Nested for loops

Tags: c++, csv, nested-loops

I am writing a program that modifies data in a csv file.
In the csv file, the **COLUMNS** are organized as follows..

X-coordinate, Y-coordinate, Z-coordinate, info, X, Y, Z, info, X, Y, Z info..

**The first X-coordinate begins in column 4 and the next one is 4 columns after, in 8**. For Y, it's column 5 and column 9, so on. Since I saved the data onto a deque, the first ones correspond to data[row#][3] for x, and y would be data[row#][5].

```
for(int k=0; k<618; k++) { //all rows  618
    for(int l=3; l<96; l=l+4) { //x columns
        for(int m=4; m<97; m=m+4) { //y columns
            data[k][l] = (data[k][l] )*(data[k][2]) + (data[k][m])*(data[k][1]);
```

In the calculation in the loop, I want it to replace all the x values (l) in columns (k) with the value I get from this equation (as I created for the loop)

```
x' = x* cos(theta) + y* sin(theta)
```

the values for cos(theta) and sin(theta) are found in columns 2 and 3 for all the rows (hence, data[k][2] and data[k][1].

Unfortunately, in testing this out with several cout statements, I noticed it is not doing as desired.

**DESIRED BEHAVIOR OF LOOP:**

- 1st time through loop: Calculation is done for row 1, x = value inside column 4 and y= value in col.5
- *end of loop iteration, re-start, k, l, and m get updated to 2,9,10.
- Calculation in the loop is executed for these new values, so on.

**Main issue is k, l, m are not all three being updated as desired after the data[k][l] line** What could be causing this?
Thank you.

Comment: What did your debugger show, when you stepped through?

Comment: Your language is unclear. After the first execution of `data[k][l]...`, only **m** should be updated. What do you observe?

Comment: @Beta I apologize. Yes, it is only updating m but I want it to update both m and l - for it to do something like this (pardon the wrong syntax, it's to get the point across)                            for(int l=19 && m=20; l<30 && m<30; l=l+4 && m=m+4)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ that it only updates m the first time through and not both m and l. How can I have it increment both l and m after 1 iteration of the data[k][l] line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not understand nested loops.

What you intend is something like this:

```
for(int k=0; k<618; k++) { //all rows  618
  for(int n=0; n<24; ++n) { //groups
    l = 4*n + 3;
    m = 4*n + 4
    data[k][l] = (data[k][l] )*(data[k][2]) + (data[k][m])*(data[k][1]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I had tried solving it myself before seeing this - would this also be a solution? codeshare.io/QAl5Z

Comment: @user3295674: Yes, if  you remember to initialize `l`.